# Workouts for increasing T levels?

Tags: workout-routines

What are some good home exercises meant more for increasing T levels rather than muscle gain?

I'm aware deadlifts and squats more than fit the bill  - what about home workouts? As someone with shite genetics and extremely low T levels at age 24 (!), I need them more than ever. Bonus points if the exercises are validated in papers/science literature

Answer (score 10):

1. Please stop saying that you have shit genetics, everyone here, except you agrees that you have fairly normal genetics and you are just comparing yourself to the people who have either been in the gym much longer than you or the people with freaky genetics.
2. Seriously, go see a therapist.
3. I want to go over the bloodwork that you posted in your last question. The test showed you were in normal reference range for everything, so I'm a bit perplexed as to why you insist that you have "extremely low T levels at 24".

[image]

**Testosterone Total: 388 ng/dl**

The current normal reference ranges for testosterone in a healthy young non obese
male population from a [study done in 2017](https://academic.oup.com/jcem/article/102/4/1161/2884621) which included 9054 healthy males aged from 19 - 39 years put the **normal reference range** between 264-916 ng/dL. This cuts off the bottom 2.5% of males and top 2.5% of males as genetic outliers, or people using androgens. Males lower than 264 ng/dL are the ones that should be concerned about their T levels, not you.

| Non-obese men percentile | 19-39 years old |
| --- | --- |
| 2.5 | 267 |
| 5.0 | 304 |
| 10.0 | 344 |
| 25.0 | 424 |
| 50.0 | 531 |
| 75.0 | 643 |
| 90.0 | 774 |
| 95.0 | 850 |
| 97.5 | 929 |

As you can see, that one blood test put you around the 20th percentile. That isn't great, but it is far better than your claim "*extremely low T levels at age 24*". More accurately, you had slightly lower than the median young healthy male for a singular blood analysis where you even admitted to having insomnia before doing the bloodwork. Insomnia plus drawing the blood at a suboptimal time during the day can drop your Testosterone total by 200 easily. There is a good chance that simply fixing your sleep can put you above median category without anything extra.

**Testosterone Free: 8.1 ng/dL**

Again, you are in the normal reference range, you have a 8.1 ng/dL and the normal reference range is 4.5-25 ng/dL. Free testosterone is the testosterone that isn't already bound to SHBG or serum albumin.

**% Testosterone Free: 2.09%**

Typically 98% of testosterone in your body is bound, so you are doing better than average here.

**Testosterone Bioavailable: 220.67 ng/dL**

The normal reference range here is 108-500 ng/dL, and you are well within normal again. This is the testosterone that is not bound by SHBG, but can be bound by serum albumin. Serum albumin has a weak bond to testosterone, so it is still bioavailable.

**% Testosterone Bioavailable: 56.87%**

56.87% is completely normal.

**Sex Hormone Binding Globulin: 27 nmol/L**

The normal reference range here is 10-57 nmol/L, again nothing out of the ordinary here.

Optimal in this blood test does **NOT** mean average. It means best case scenario, great genetics with great fitness. Most people will never be in that range without androgenic agents for free or total testosterone. The reason the company lists those values as optimal is because they are trying to sell you HRT/TRT or something similar. As far as your hormones from this test, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I waa told by the person who did the bloodwork this was something to be concerned about at my age (24), and he proposed giving me some T boosting tablets (I forget the brand name). So you can understand why I would be concerned, given that it's coming from an actual doctor and not an internet stranger (no offense, and I meant that - I appreciate the time you took to write your viewpoint)

Comment: I'm glad that you don't take everything from a random internet stranger for face value. That is a good thing. Please also get an opinion from a second doctor in person before taking anything that "boosts testosterone". The issue with taking exogenous anabolic agents is that it will shut down your natural production and often your body doesn't start it back up afterward coming off, forcing you to take them forever. If it isn't testosterone, and just something that boosts testosterone, be very skeptical. Often it raises both testosterone and SHBG making absolutely no difference in your life.